# Printing the data retrieved from database as response in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'am beginner of node.js,Sorry if I went wrong.

Instead of printing data in console.log(),I want to print at localhost:3000.

Here I retrieved data from MYsql database,Everything went right when I done with console.log().
But it went wrong when I written my code with http request and response.

My db.js is

```
  var http = require("http");
  var port = 3000;
  var serverUrl = "localhost";
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({

        host : 'localhost',
        user : username,
        password: password,
        database: "wst"

  });

   var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

   console.log("Request: " + req.url);
   connection.connect();

   connection.query('select * from welcome',function(err, results, fields){

    //console.log(results);
    //console.log(fields);
     var html = "<p>Registered users are " + results + ".</p>";
     res.end(html);

        });

    connection.end();

  });



  console.log("Listening at " + serverUrl + ":" + port);

  server.listen(port, serverUrl);
```

And the output in browser is:

Registered users are [object Object],[object Object].

And error in command prompt is:

cannot enqueue handshake after invoking quit.

If I'm completely wrong give me some tutorials on node.js.

Comment: try, `"<p>Registered users are " + util.inspect(results) + ".</p>";`

Comment: Use util.inspect or JSON.stringify/parse

Comment: @thefourtheye   yeah it worked thanks.But still giving "Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you're doing some processing on the client to bind it to a template after fetching it through ajax?

Given that, you should consider not doing any templating on the server and instead just sending the json data, e.g. rather than `<p>Registered users are " + util.inspect(results) + ".</p>";` you would just do `util.inspect(results)`.

You'll probably want to set the Content-Type header as well to `application/json` so that any magic your clientside framework wants to do by inspecting the headers will work.